# Traversable for data Constant a b = Constant a passes Quickchecks, but acts funny

Tags: haskell, traversable

The haskell book wants me to implement the traversable instance for

```
newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a }
```

including all necessary superclasses. The code below passes `Quickcheck/Checkers`, but acts funny

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers
import Test.QuickCheck.Classes

newtype Constant a b = Constant { getConstant :: a }

instance Functor (Constant a) where
  fmap f (Constant a) = Constant a

instance Foldable (Constant a) where
  foldr f z (Constant x) = z

instance Traversable (Constant a) where
  traverse f (Constant a) = pure $ Constant a    

type TI = []
main = do
  let trigger = undefined :: TI (Int, Int, [Int])
  quickBatch (traversable trigger)
```

When I try to use the traversable instance like so:

```
traverse (\x -> [x + 1]) $ Constant 5
```

I do not get `Constant [5]` which I was hoping for, but rather

```
traverse (\x -> [x + 1]) $ Constant 5
  :: (Num b, Num a) => [Constant a b]
```

What does it mean? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: A Haskell koan: `Constant 5` does not contain the constant `5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I try to use the traversable instance like so:
>
> ```
> traverse (\x -> [x + 1]) $ Constant 5
> ```
>
> I do not get `Constant [5]` which I was hoping for [...]

You're not going to get `Constant [5]`.  Let's write the type for `traverse`:

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

...and line it up with your instantiation of it:

```
                  -- I've substituted `x` for `a` and `y` for `b` in the
                  -- first type, because otherwise my head hurts.
                  (x -> f  y) -> t            x -> f  (t            y)
(Num a, Num b) => (a -> [] a) -> (Constant b) a -> [] ((Constant b) a)
```

So we have:

```
t = Constant b
f = []
x = Num a => a
y = NUm b => b
```

Note that the type for `traverse` implies that `t` will be the same in the argument and the result.  Since you're using `Constant 5 :: Num a => Constant a b` as the argument, that implies that you can never have `Constant [5] :: Num a => Constant [a] b` in the result, because `Constant a /= Constant [a]`.

Comment: Thanks, will think about it. Is my implementation correct?

Comment: Still, it does not return `Constant 5` or anything concrete either, it just returns a type with a constraint or something similar...

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: Your implementation looks correct. One exercise you could try to appreciate this is this: how would you write a different `Traversable` instance for `Constant`?  (Hint: it's a trick question!) Anyway, your example should evaluate to the value `[Constant 5]`; you should be able to pattern match against the result to verify that. That's the point of the `Constant` functor—it's a limit case for `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Traversable` that just ignores the functions you're mapping over it.